Automate express route circuit gateway based on express route circuit provision status
I want to create express route gateway based on express route circuit provision status using terraform . When express route circuit is created initial provider status will be unprovisioned. once it is provisioined in equinix portal this status changes to provisioned.To change this status, it would take few days,till then express route gateway need not be created as it a bit expensive resource.when i run pipeline, initially express route circuit will be created and it's status will be unprovisioned, now in this state express route gateway creation should be skipped. When the status is changed to provisioned, I will run the pipeline , here it has to check the provision status only when changed to provisioned, express route gateway should be created .
 resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example-express-rg" {
  name     = "example-vnet-rg"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "vnettest" {
  name                = "example-vnet"
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example-express-rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example-express-rg.name
}

resource "azurerm_subnet" "gateway_subnet" {
  name                 = "GatewaySubnet"
  resource_group_name  = azurerm_resource_group.example-express-rg.name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnettest.name
  address_prefixes     = ["10.0.1.0/24"]
}

resource "azurerm_public_ip" "publicip" {
  name                = "example-public-ip"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example-express-rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example-express-rg.name
  allocation_method   = "Static"
  sku                 = "Standard"

}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "expressrg" {
  name     = "exprtTest"
  location = "West Europe"
}
resource "azurerm_express_route_circuit" "expressr" {
  name                  = "expressRoute1"
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.expressrg.name
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.expressrg.location
  service_provider_name = "Equinix"
  peering_location      = "Singapore"
  bandwidth_in_mbps     = 1000

  sku {
    tier   = "Standard"
    family = "MeteredData"
  }

  tags = {
    Purpose = "Resource"
    ResorceOwner ="CCTeam"
  }
}

# Data Source to Check the Status of the ExpressRoute Circuit
data "azurerm_express_route_circuit" "expressr_status" {
  name                = azurerm_express_route_circuit.expressr.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.expressrg.name
}
# Virtual Network Gateway (Create Conditionally)

resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "example" {
  depends_on = [azurerm_express_route_circuit.expressr]
  count               =data.azurerm_express_route_circuit.expressr_status.service_provider_provisioning_state == "Provisioned" ? 1 : 0
  name                = "testgw"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example-express-rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example-express-rg.name
  type     = "ExpressRoute"
  vpn_type = "PolicyBased"
  sku           = "Standard"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "vnetGatewayConfig"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.publicip.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.gateway_subnet.id
  }
  
  tags = {
    Purpose = "Resource"
    ResorceOwner ="CCTeam"
  }
}

I tried using data block and condition but it results with error
Error: Invalid count argument
│
│   on main.tf line 75, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "example":
│   75:   count               =data.azurerm_express_route_circuit.expressr_status.service_provider_provisioning_state == "Provisioned" ? 1 : 0
│
│ The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how
│ many instances will be created. To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the resources that the
│ count depends on.
Please suggest me on this .

we cant refer a data resoource while using count @deepika

noted. But in this case, can you please suggest me how to achieve this .

instead, you can use null resource conditioned logic helps you verifying the status @deepika

output "provisioning_state" {
value = data.azurerm_express_route_circuit.expressr.service_provider_provisioning_state
}
locals {
provisioned_state = data.azurerm_express_route_circuit.expressr.service_provider_provisioning_state == "Provisioned"
}

resource "null_resource" "express_route_gateway_trigger" {
depends_on = [azurerm_express_route_circuit.expressr]
provisioner "local-exec" {
when = "create"
command = "echo 'Provisioning state is ${local.provisioned_state}, so creating ExpressRoute gateway...'"
}
triggers = {
provisioning_state = local.provisioned_state
}
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "example" {
count = local.provisioned_state ? 1 : 0
name                = "testgw"
location            = azurerm_resource_group.example-express-rg.location
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example-express-rg.name
type                = "ExpressRoute"
sku                 = "Standard"
ip_configuration {
name                          = "vnetGatewayConfig"
public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.publicip.id
subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.gateway_subnet.id
}
}

@VinayB - I have tried to fetch the provisioning_state using output and created a null resource.
Error: Invalid count argument
│
│   on main.tf line 96, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "example":
│   96:   count = local.provisioned_state ? 1 : 0
│
│ The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will
│ be created. To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the resources that the count depends on.
can you please suggest me what to do here

    data "azurerm_express_route_circuit" "expressr" {
  name                = azurerm_express_route_circuit.expressr.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.expressrg.name
}

output "provisioning_state" { 
  value = data.azurerm_express_route_circuit.expressr.service_provider_provisioning_state 
} 


locals {
  express_route_exists = try(data.azurerm_express_route_circuit.expressr.name != "", false)
 
  actual_provisioned_state = local.express_route_exists && try(data.azurerm_express_route_circuit.expressr.service_provider_provisioning_state == "Provisioned")
 
  create_gateway = var.provisioned_state == "Provisioned" || local.actual_provisioned_state =="Provisioned"
}

#Virtual Network Gateway (Create Conditionally)
variable "provisioned_state" {
  default = "NotProvisioned"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "example" {
  count = local.create_gateway ? 1 : 0 
  name                = "testgw"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example-express-rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example-express-rg.name
  type                = "ExpressRoute"
  vpn_type            = "PolicyBased"
  sku                 = "Standard"

This worked out in this scenario


Automating express route circuit gateway based on express route circuit provision status using terraform

The configuration you shared checks with the availability of provision state in the virtual network gateway which results in error as in present inside the configuration we may need the local exec to validate the state of the express route
Since it will take some days to provision, I just mentioned the structural changes as per the requirement
Demo Configuration:
resource "azurerm_express_route_circuit" "expressr" {
  name                  = var.express_route_name
  resource_group_name   = azurerm_resource_group.expressrg.name
  location              = azurerm_resource_group.expressrg.location
  service_provider_name = "Equinix"
  peering_location      = "Silicon Valley"
  bandwidth_in_mbps     = 50

  sku {
    tier   = "Standard"
    family = "MeteredData"
  }
}


data "azurerm_express_route_circuit" "expressr_status" {
  name                = azurerm_express_route_circuit.expressr.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.expressrg.name
}


resource "null_resource" "check_provision_status" {
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    interpreter = ["pwsh", "-Command"]
    command = <<EOT
$status = "${data.azurerm_express_route_circuit.expressr_status.service_provider_provisioning_state}"
if ($status -ne "Provisioned") {
    Write-Output "ExpressRoute circuit is not provisioned. Skipping gateway creation."
    exit 1
} else {
    Write-Output "ExpressRoute circuit is provisioned. Proceeding with gateway creation."
    exit 0
}
EOT
  }

  triggers = {
    status = data.azurerm_express_route_circuit.expressr_status.service_provider_provisioning_state
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "example" {
  depends_on          = [null_resource.check_provision_status]
  name                = "tesvksgw"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example-express-rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example-express-rg.name
  type                = "ExpressRoute"
  vpn_type            = "PolicyBased"
  sku                 = "Standard"

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "vnetvkGatewayConfig"
    public_ip_address_id          = azurerm_public_ip.publicip.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.gateway_subnet.id
  }
}


After provisioning the configuration, the output might look like this
Deployment:

Here state was still showing as not provisioned because it was recently created, and we need to wait for the provision state to change from provider end
If the resource was already provisioned and then null resource will validate the status of the resources and continue with the rest of the configuration.
refer:
https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/null/latest/docs/resources/resource
https://build5nines.com/terraform-deploy-azure-expressroute-circuit-with-vnet-gateway/

Error: local-exec provisioner error
with null_resource.check_provision_status,on main.tf line 74, in resource "null_resource" "check_provision_status":
74:   provisioner "local-exec" {
Error running command '$status = "NotProvisioned"
if ($status -ne "Provisioned") {
Write-Output "ExpressRoute circuit is not provisioned. Skipping gateway creation."
exit 1
} else {
Write-Output "ExpressRoute circuit is provisioned. Proceeding with gateway creation.exit 0}': exit status 1.
Output: ExpressRoute circuit is not provisioned. Skipping gateway creation.Is this error expected?

Yes, the error is expected because the local-exec provisioner exits with status 1 when the ExpressRoute circuit is "NotProvisioned". Re-run the pipeline once the circuit's status is updated to "Provisioned". @deepika

thanks, this would be really  helpful. But  in my case, they want to set default variable to not provisioned . and use in express route gateway creation . when status is provisioned in that case, it has to refer the service_provider_provisioning_state. I have tried below method . but i am finding it difficult to include service_provider_provisioning_state status .
count =var.provisioned_state ? 1 : 0
like this it has to check for local.provisioned_state but initially it has to refer to variable , only when express route circuit exists then this attribute should be referred

and also they want to eliminate null resource

set a default variable like var.provisioned_state to NotProvisioned. Use a local block to dynamically check the service_provider_provisioning_state only when the ExpressRoute Circuit exists

locals {
provisioned_state = var.provisioned_state == "Provisioned" || try(data.azurerm_express_route_circuit.expressr_status.service_provider_provisioning_state == "Provisioned", false)
}
resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "example" {
count = local.provisioned_state ? 1 : 0
other properties...
}

Error: Invalid count argument
│
│   on main.tf line 84, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "example":
│   84:   count = local.provisioned_state ? 1 : 0
│
│ The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, so Terraform
│ cannot predict how many instances will be created. To work around this, use the -target argument to
│ first apply only the resources that the count depends on.
i am getting this error ,

are you using the same condition which i shared ?

yeah... i have tried the same one

locals {
express_route_exists = try(data.azurerm_express_route_circuit.expressr.name != "", false)
Determine the actual provisioning state
actual_provisioned_state = local.express_route_exists && try(data.azurerm_express_route_circuit.expressr.service_provider_provisioning_state, "NotProvisioned")
Final condition to decide whether to create the gateway
create_gateway = var.provisioned_state == "Provisioned" || local.actual_provisioned_state == "Provisioned"
}
#Virtual Network Gateway (Create Conditionally)
variable "provisioned_state" {
default = "NotProvisioned"
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "example" {
count = local.create_gateway ? 1 : 0
I have tried above condition. but now that they want this condition to check using binary . i mean actual_provisioned_state should be referred as true or false

locals { create_gateway = var.provisioned_state == "Provisioned" || (try(data.azurerm_express_route_circuit.expressr.service_provider_provisioning_state, "NotProvisioned") == "Provisioned") }  try this once

Error: Invalid count argument
│
│   on main.tf line 89, in resource "azurerm_virtual_network_gateway" "example":
│   89:   count = local.create_gateway ? 1 : 0
│
│ The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created. To
│ work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the resources that the count depends on.
Getting this error. the one i have provided at Dec 6 at 11:39. This is working. but they want the expression using boolean

I am so thankful for your patience and guidance .Thanks for this helpful conversations &  suggestions
